# obtain the inbound SMS number in Twilio function

Tags: javascript, sms, twilio, twilio-api

I want to write a Twilio function in node.js that can be reused by multiple phone numbers in my Twilio account. In this function I need to obtain the inbound (called or messaged) Twilio number that triggered the function.

For example, if my function forwards an SMS to email, I need not only `event.From` and `event.Body`, I also need the "To" number. But `event.to` is **undefined** and it appears to be intended for another purpose.

I could also use the *friendlyName* configured for this number.

How do I obtain either of these values in a Twilio function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here. I think what you want to get the Twilio phone number that is texted is `event.To` with a capital *T*.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible (in this context) to get the Friendly Name defined for the phone number?

Comment: See the answer in your other post ;)